# Order by meta_value when meta_key equals value. MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to order a number of posts. Each has a number of meta_keys and meta_values.

One of these meta_keys is a date.

I would like to order posts by this date like this -

```
"Select * 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id ='$ID' 
ORDER BY meta_value 
WHEN meta_key = 'date'"
```

Which is not working.

I can produce an unordered list. So seek advice on how to ORDER BY a particular meta_value when the meta_key is 'date'?

Comment: `WHERE post_id ='$ID' AND  meta_key = 'date' ORDER BY meta_value`

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query

```
"Select * 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id ='$ID' 
AND meta_key = 'date'
ORDER BY meta_value 
"
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Which is what I wrote [`15 mins. prior`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326932/order-by-meta-value-when-meta-key-equals-value-mysql#comment39481595_25326932) to this, but OP hasn't responded to it. So, either the OP has gone and gotten breakfast and/or getting a large coffee, or did not accept it.

Comment: You are saying right if he is there than he would have responded to the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
"Select * 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id ='$ID' 
AND meta_key = 'date'
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(meta_value , '%d/%m/%Y')
"
```

Comment: Considere adding comments with your code. This is not an answer.

Comment: @ArnaudPeralta it is an answer as it attempts to answer the question. An explanation is preferred, but it isn't required, nor does a missing explanation warrant flagging and/or review deletion, assuming it's otherwise ok.